# Find Position of Character contained in List

Tags: python, python-3.x

if I got this variable

```
operator = ["&", "/", "->", "<->", "X", "I"]
expression = "p&q->rXq"
```

how could I return the position of `"&"` and `"X"` inside `operator? i need the output something like this:

> ```
> 1:0, 3:2, 6:4
> #1 for "&", 3 for "->", 6 for "X" inside expression variable.
> #0 for "&", 2 for "->", 4 for "X" inside operator List.
> ```

Comment: Why do you have the variable `expression` at all?

Comment: @JeremyMcGibbon I Edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
operator = ["&", "/", "->", "<->", "X", "I"]
expression = "p&q->rXq"

resultString = ''
for one_op in operator: # for each character in your list
    startingIndex = expression.find(one_op) # important: assuming it appears only once, find() takes the first occurrence and returns the index
    if startingIndex is not -1: # if find() does not find an occurence, it will return -1
        resultString += (str(startingIndex) + ':' + str(operator.index(one_op)) + ',') # only that exist is considered

print(resultString.rstrip(','))
```

Output:

```
1:0,3:2,6:4
```

Answer (score 4):

```
operator = ["&", "/", "->", "<->", "X", "I"]
expression = "p&q->rXq"
print(operator.index("<->"))
```

This will show output:

> 3

Is this what you want?

Comment: I Edited the question